# Fill Second input with the First input information

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't now how I can do this.. Example:

I have **2** `inputs` and when I fill the First `input` with the time and Second `input` add **+2 hours**.

**Example:**

First `input` = 10:00

Second `input` automatically put: 12:00

Comment: Welcome to SO. It really helps to post example code of what you have tried. Also any errors or what you're expecting to see.

Comment: `I don't now how I can do this.. `

Comment: We got to start somewhere. What HTML code you have currently?

Comment: if its all dynamic (javascript) then you don't need php tag, same for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a date object and just add two hours, that has the advantage of making `23:00` become `01:00` etc. without any hassle.

Then it's just a matter of adding an event handler, getting the value, creating a date object, adding two hours, getting the hours back, and putting it as the value in the other input

```
var first  = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');

first.addEventListener('input', function() {

    if (this.value.indexOf(':') != -1 && this.value.length === 5) {

        var date  = new Date();
        var val   = this.value.split(':');
        date.setHours( parseInt(val[0], 10) + 2);

        var hours = date.getHours();
        hours = hours > 9 ? hours : '0' + hours;

        second.value = hours + ':' + val[1];
    }

}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/o7w499t4/2/)

Comment: In midnight to 9am how I can put the zero before?

Comment: Doesn't it already do that ?